# I’m Trying to Separate the First Post From the Rest of the Loop

Tags: loop

The layout I’m marking up and styling calls for the first post to be full width while the rest of the posts are not. Here’s my block of code:

```
<main>
<?php
// Define how the loop will fetch posts
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post', // Set the post type to 'post'
  'posts_per_page' => 7, // Display 7 posts
  'orderby' => 'date', // Order posts by date
  'order'   => 'DESC', // Display posts in descending order (newest to oldest)
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
  <section>
<?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <article>
      <header>
        <div>
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read now</a>›</p>
        </div>
      </header>
    </article>
    <div class="wrapper">
<?php while ( $loop -> have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 
      <article>
        <header>
          <div>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read now</a>›</p>
          </div>
        </header>
      </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<? else : ?>
    <article>
      <p>Sorry, no posts were found!</p>
    </article>
<?php endif; ?>
  </section>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</main>
```

Unfortunately, the message “Sorry, no posts were found!” is being displayed along with the posts. What am I doing wrong? Please help! Moving back the `else :` to the same line as `endwhile;` makes it work but I need the it to be after the `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried switching from `:` and `endif;` or `endwhile;` to brackets it worked.